# Почему на XFCE перетаскиваемое окно отстает от мышки?

Tags: manjaro, xfce4, draggable, мышь

У меня свежая Манжара XFCE на новом ноутбуке Intel HD-530 Graphic и почему-то когда я хватаю мышкой окно за шапку и тащу его в сторону, оно как бы отстает от курсора. Чем быстрее тащу , тем больше отстает.

А когда останавливаю мышку, то окно за 0.1-0.2 секнуды догоняет ее и занимает свое положенное место под мышой. Выглядит как буд-то оно не успевает что-ли. Странное такое лагание на 1-2 сантиметра.

На предыдущем ноуте с предыдущей графикой тоже Intel такого не было. То есть как бы быстро я не тянул окно, оно всегда было под мышой.

Все версии последние. Только только обновил все из репозитория Манжары. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Очевидно что причина в проприетарных драйверах (если они вообще имеются). Попробуйте попереключаться между разными версиями и с открытыми тоже сравните.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf Нет. Прорприетарных драйверов для интела не имеется. :-)

Comment: Сравнив конфигурашки со старым ноутом, понял из-за чего тормозит. Это все Композер. Как только его отключаешь, сразу скорость перерисовки возрастает. Специально замерил производительнсоть с ним и без него ,  и оказалось в бенчмарке с Компзозером 8тыс балов, без него 14тыс балов. Почему такая большая разница???

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте для начала переставить интеловский стек. Может из этого списка что-то не доставилось. `sudo pacman -Syu xf86-video-intel libva-intel-driver intel-media-sdk intel-media-driver vulkan-intel intel-ucode intel-tbb intel-gmmlib libmfx lib32-vulkan-intel` и перезагрузитесь.

Comment: Я выполнил эту команду. Несколько пакетов доустановилось в результате. Но ничего не изменилось.